# Conditional Conjunction of two Iterables

Tags: python, set, iterable

I have an odd situation that is causing me confusion (and errors.) I've renamed the variables to be more clear, but the problem is real. I have two iterables that I need to combine. The combination should be a conjunction without repetition. However, if an element is the "opposite" of another, neither should exist in the final set.

Conceptual Example: (a, b, c) COMBINE (b, c', d) -> (a, b, d) # Let c be opposite of c'

Here is my current implementation that fails in part because I am trying to modify the size of a set while iterating over it:

```
# atom_list and atom_set are distinct not only in their type but also their contents.
for atom in atom_list:
    should_add = True
    for other_atom in atom_set:
        if atom.is_opposite(other_atom):
            # Todo: cause anti-matter/matter explosion!!
            atom_set.remove(other_atom)
            should_add = False
    if should_add:
        atom_set.add(atom)
```

Are there any thoughts as to how to make this cleaner (and work without modifying the set that I'm iterating over)? I feel like a good solution to this problem will involve more than just copying the set at first...

Comment: Suppose you have an atom called `a`.  Is it possible to do something like `if a.opposite() in atom_set`?  That would probably be faster and easier to read.

Comment: What magic functions would need to be supported for that to work?

Comment: @Kevin That is, I could write an `opposite` function. Would `__eq__` be all that I'd have to worry about in addition?

Comment: What about `(a, b, c, c') COMBINE (...)` - should I keep c?

Comment: @dmitry_romanov That would be an invariant violation in my situation. You can assume it won't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say modifying the iterable while iterating over it is not a good idea. Why not create another set?

```
combined_set = set()
for atom in atom_list:
    if atom.opposite() not in atom_set:
        combined_set.add(atom)

atom_list_set = set(atom_list)
for atom in atom_set:
    if atom not in atom_list_set:
        combined_set.add(atom)
```

This assumes that an `opposite()` method exists which returns the opposite of an atom. The second `for` loop handles atoms which are in atom_set but not in atom_list.

Comment: Wouldn't that add too many atoms? If the case where two atoms are compared that are not opposites but an opposite exists later in the sets, that would add the atom anyway, no?

Comment: @BlackVegetable, you are correct - I have updated my answer with a modification which may not be possible. It depends on the presence of a method `opposite()`. This is also a requirement for the other answer.

Comment: Yes, this is a function I can write, however. I find this more readable than a list comprehension, if perhaps less Pythonic. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, but one question before I accept. Will I need to implement a magic function like `__in__` or `__eq__` as well?

Comment: No, if atom is hashable no magic functions are needed. The `opposite()` method should return an atom object.

Comment: See my updated code for the fix - I apologize for the horrible name `atom_list_set` but was in a hurry!

Answer (score 0):

Quick 'dirty' solution:

```
s1 = set([1, 2, 3])
s2 = set([4, -2, 5])
res = [x for x in s1 | s2 if -x not in s1 and -x not in s2]
```

2 and -2 are opposite elements which we exclude. It gives `[1, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: I think I follow this. Can you clarify for future readers why this works? (+1, will accept if no other, more-readable answers are proposed.)

Comment: this wont add elements if the opposite of an element exists in the same set, i don't know if that's an issue or not for you though

Comment: @GP89 As stated in a comment-exchange between me and this author, that won't ever be the case in my situation.

Comment: @BlackVegetable ahh didn't see that. If you're on `2.7+` or `3.x` you can replace the `[` `]` with `{` `}` to make a set comprehension